# Can't install any ruby with RVM-Capistrano

Tags: ruby, rvm, centos, rvm-capistrano

I recently installed the gem rvm-capistrano in order to deploy in my server. First, I tried to run `cap deploy:setup`. It seems that installed RVM, but for some reasons (permissions or something else), it couldn't install REE:

```
Warning:
*** [err :: myserver.com] Failed to create the file ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02.tar.gz
[...]

There was an error, please check /usr/local/rvm/log//*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
 ** [out :: myserver.com] Trying ftp:// URL instead.
```

I didn't include more because is irrelevant.

Obviously in `deploy.rb` sudo options is set as `'root'`.

Comment: Seems like a permission issue, post your log from  /usr/local/rvm/log/

Comment: also the log looks short, please post whole output and best would be to see your script.

Answer (score 1):

```
adduser #{user} rvm
```

Fixed it for me. Where `#{user}` is the name of your cap deploy user.